# BST setting height at each pointing node

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement recursive method to set recursively the height at each node. Partially solution is achieved, however I am not entirely sure where I could decrement height and check if particular node in-Order traversal is complete. My program is based on this implementation: http://visualgo.net/bst.html

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for height here to represent the level of the tree that a node is on, using a global variable is going to give you pretty weird results. I also admit to not being entirely sure what you are doing with the variable `u`.

That said, I think you should be okay with something like this:

```
public void setHeight(struct node *r, int h = -1) {
    // pointer pointing to null, return
    if(r == NULL)  {
        return;
    }
    h++; // increment height
    r.height = h; // set update height to a current node

    setHeight(r ->u.lc, h); // traverse the list pointing to the left child
    visit(r) // visit pointing node
    setHeight(r ->u.rc, h); // visit right child of the node
}
```

Edit: I don't have the reputation to comment yet, so I'm limited to responding with edits. @ProgLearner, you don't need a separate variable `u` because your node pointer is a function argument, and so you'll have a fresh one with every call to the function. Similarly, as Jonathan Mee said, the `h` variable needs no external initialization because it's also local to the function. In cases where you don't supply any initial value (like when you call it on the root), it will default to -1.

Comment: @ProgLearner The defaulting of `setHeight` means that when called with the root node, no `h` parameter needs to be passed.

Comment: Thanks. u represents all nodes, so it can anywhere in the tree. it will contain h representing current hight. I am not entirely sure about struct node *r, int h = -1), I guess h =-1 has to be initialized somewhere and then you just pass to a function

Comment: @Jonathan Mee but then where you going to store temp h value. Do you mean determine current height based on a current node and then increment/decrement?

Comment: @ProgLearner Note that [Mindful](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4243650/mindful)'s `setHeight` calls itself recursively. When you call `setHeight(rootNode)` `h` will take on the default value of -1 in the function. All future recursive calls will pass along the value of `h` so that the correct position in the tree is kept track of _without_ a global.